# Binding image source in knockout dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to bind a new image path to image , I have a popup ,where on select of checkbox,I get a new image path which  I need to bind with the image of parent window, so I have a public function which is getting called on selection of checkbox in popup page,
Below is what i tried,

```
 <a data-bind="attr:{href: thumburl , target:'_self'}" class="light">
                        <img data-bind="attr: {src: Image} " />
                    </a>
```

javascript :

```
<script>
   function parentFunc(path) {
    // I get the new path here. 
    }

 $(function () {
     var audioObject = {
        ID:0,
        Image: "",
        ContentID: 0
    }

    function Audio(data) {
        var self = this;
        this.thumburl = ko.observable("http://localhost:61437/Admin/Thumbnail/Play?ContentID=" + data.ContentID);

        console.log('mapping to js', data);
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, audioObject, self);
    }
     // as it is an edit page, I am loading the data using id.
    var loadData = function (id) {
        var _url = '/api/v2/my/audio';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: _url + '/' + id,
            success: function (d) {
                if (!!d.error) { console.log(d.message); }
                else {
                    var model = new Audio(d);
                    ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("audioEdit"));
                    console.log(model);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    loadData(@ViewBag.Id);
});
```

Any suggestions on what can I do to make this work?? 
New to knockout!!

Answer (score 2):

You're applying a view-model to your view correctly:

```
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("audioEdit"));
```

but the problem is that the Image property isn't inside this view-model so KO cannot find it.

What you could do is something like:

Make the audioObject your view model and add a audio property which will eventually hold the Audio() object. Make the Image property observable.

```
 var audioViewModel = {
    ID:0,
    Image: ko.observable(""),
    ContentID: 0,
    audio: null
}
```

Create your Audio() object, but add it in to the view-model:

```
var model = new Audio(d);
audioViewModel.audio = model;
```

Apply bindings as before but with your new view-model:

```
ko.applyBindings(audoViewModel, document.getElementById("audioEdit"));
```

Tweak your bind statements slightly:

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href: audio.thumburl , target:'_self'}" class="light">
    <img data-bind="attr: {src: Image} " />
</a>
```

Your parentFunc then needs to set the Image observable:

```
function parentFunc(path) {
    // I get the new path here.
    audioViewModel.Image(new_image_path); 
}
```

I spotted a few other problems in your code, maybe I can build a fiddle to help you fix them and understand KO a bit better.

---

EDIT: here's a fiddle, showing the above tips, plus also some other tweaks like using a computed for the thumburl:

http://jsfiddle.net/a7KVd/1/

How's that look?